# Откуда в поиске появились клоны страницы вида - мой сайт/?domain=www.ivanovokredit.ru

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Недавно заметил что в поиске появляются клоны страницы моего сайта вида - `мой сайт/?domain=www.ivanovokredit.ru, мой сайт/?refferal=poisk-stroy_ru, мой сайт/?add=5124&from=regwidgets.city`. Которые ведут на главную страницу моего сайта (клоны).
 Думаю сделано это с целью понижения в ПС (не уникальный контент). В robots.txt добавил строчку `Disallow: *?*` , но при написании в строке адреса браузера - `мой сайт/?refferal=poisk-stroy_ru` все равно открывется главная страница, адрес в строке остается. 404 ая страница тоже в этом случае отказывается работать. 
Что это ? Вредоносный код? И как сделать перенаправление с таких страниц 301-й редирект через .htaccess чтобы перенаправлялось все после знака вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Это не клоны, и контент остается уникальным. В адресе вида `мой сайт/?key=arg` адресом является `мой сайт`, то есть все адреса, которые вы перечислили, указывают на ваш сайт, а не на какие-то страницы-клоны. То, что идет после знака вопроса, является аргументами, которые просто передаются вашей html странице. Использовать их или игнорировать - это исключительно дело разработчика сайта. Вы их игнорируете, поэтому на отображение или работу сайта они не влияют.

Эти левые адреса всего лишь так называемый [referrer spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam). Если они появляются в поиске, значит в поиск каким-то образом попадают ваши логи. Цель этого спама как раз и состоит в том, чтобы через ваши логи создать реферальную ссылку на спамерский сайт. Изолируйте логи от интернета, и все эти ссылки станут обычным мусором в логах, который раздражает админа, но ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Как изолировать логи от интернета?

Comment: @Анатолий, сделать их недоступными для скачивания. Сохранять их в каталоге вне дерева каталогов веб-сервера, например.